# How to declare a type that's the success return type of an async function?

Tags: typescript, promise, async-await

Is there a way to declare a variable as the success return value of an async funcion (or Promise)?

When given a function, there's the possibility of declaring a variable as

```
let foo: ReturnType<typeof myFunc>;
```

If the function is `async`,

```
let asyncFoo: ReturnType<typeof myAsyncFunc>;
```

the above variable will be typed as `Promise<{...}>`, which is close, but not quite what I'm looking for. I'd like to get the type of the `await`ed value (or the value passed into the `.then()` callback). How would that type look?

Comment: I think in the typescript 4.5 version you can use Awaited. For example: type Foo = Awaited<Promise<PromiseLike<{your resolved return value type here}>>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ['infer' keyword](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html).

```
type ExtractPromiseType<T extends Promise<any>> = 
    T extends Promise<infer U> ? U : never;

let asyncFoo: ExtractPromiseType<ReturnType<typeof myAsyncFunc>>;
```